# Lower bound on a term involving positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, upper-lower-bounds, positive-definite

If $A$ is a positive definite matrix, can we derive a lower bound for the term $x^T A y$, where $x, y$ are two vectors of the following form:
$$(x-z)^T A (x-y) \geq \alpha (x-z)^T (x-y), $$
where $\alpha$ is a positive scalar?

Comment: Cannot hold for all $z$. If you change $z$ to $2x-z$ the inequality gets reversed.